# What are "feature planes" in neural networks? (current context is deep reinforcement learning)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

*The input contains 14 feature planes, each of shape 11x11*
What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

A feature plane is just a numeric representation of a specific state of the environment.

For example, in a game with different types of items (candy, cake, bomb, ...) a binary feature plane can be used to encode the positions for each type of item.